# MySQL LEFT JOIN only one row, ordered by column without subquery

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, left-join

Is there a possibility to do LEFT JOIN with only one row from other table ordered by column (date) without using sub query. My query is below. It works but it's  super slow.

```
SELECT * FROM clients c 
LEFT JOIN loan l ON c.id = l.id_client AND l.id = (
    SELECT id FROM loan ll
    WHERE ll.id_client = c.id
    ORDER BY `create_date` DESC
    LIMIT 1) 
GROUP BY k.id DESC 
ORDER BY c.register_date DESC 
LIMIT n , m; (n,m is from pagination)
```

Is there a way to speed it up?

Comment: Instead of `AND l.id=subquery` use a join. Also the results of the EXPLAIN plan and table definitions would help.

Comment: What does your data look like?

Comment: OK, but how can I limit to 1 record only one join?
I will paste my table def later because now I don't have access. For now: Clients HAS MANY Loans so how to join only one row?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Im interpreting your question as "Get me all loan details for the most recent loan for each client"

This should work... note the assumption though.

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
    clients c 
    LEFT JOIN (select id_client, Max(id) id -- this assumes that a loan with a later create date will also have a higher id.
                from loan
                group by id_client) il
        on il.id_client = c.id
    inner join loan l
        on l.id = il.id
GROUP BY k.id DESC                          -- Dont know what "k" is
ORDER BY c.register_date DESC 
LIMIT n , m; (n,m is from pagination)
```

Comment: EXCELENT! It works great but I still don't know why your query is faster than mine. Can you please explain me that?

Comment: yours kind of says: get all loans for all clients, now get all loans for each client individually, sort the loans by date and then take the first one, and now filter the first result set for just that loan ID. ..... Mine kind of says get the most recent loan ID for each client and all the details for that loan. One reason it is faster is because I limit the result set a lot earlier so the query doesn't have to process a whole bunch of records we are going to discard anyway.

Comment: Not terribly elegant, but magnitudes faster, I'll have to remember this technique.

Comment: Is it possible to fetch more loan columns (against that desired max id), additional to just id column. ?

Comment: @HyperVol the additional columns from `loan` are available from the latter `inner join`... the one with the alias `l`.